# how to get a single value from dataframe only in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe df_my that looks like this

```
      id    name        age     major
----------------------------------------
0     1     Mark        34      English
1     2     Tom         55      Art
2     3     Peter       31      Science
3     4     Mohammad    23      Math
4     5     Mike        47      Art
...
```

I am trying to get the value of major (only)

I used this and it works fine when I know the id of the record

```
df_my["major"][3]
```

returns

```
"Math"
```

great

but I want to get the major for a variable record

I used

```
i = 3
df_my.loc[df_my["id"]==i]["major"]
```

and also used

```
i = 3
df_my[df_my["id"]==i]["major"]
```

but they both return

```
3     Math
```

it includes the record index too

how can I get the major only and nothing else?

Comment: you can try `.to_list()` so in your example: `df_my[df_my["id"]==i]["major"].to_list()`

Comment: `df_my.loc[df_my["id"]==i]["major"]`(where i is 3) should return `Science` right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `squeeze`:

```
i = 3
out = df.loc[df['id']==i,'major'].squeeze()
```

Another option is `iat`:

```
out = df.loc[df['id']==i,'major'].iat[0]
```

Output:

```
'Science'
```

Answer (score 0):

I also stumbled over this problem, from a little different angle:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'First Name': ['Kumar'],
                   'Last Name': ['Ram'],
                   'Country': ['India'],
                   'num_var': 1})

>>> df.loc[(df['First Name'] == 'Kumar'), "num_var"]
0    1
Name: num_var, dtype: int64

>>> type(df.loc[(df['First Name'] == 'Kumar'), "num_var"])
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

So it returns a Series (although it is only a series with only 1 element). If you access through the index, you receive the integer.

```
df.loc[0, "num_var"]
1

type(df.loc[0, "num_var"])
<class 'numpy.int64'>
```

The answer on how to select the respective, single value was already given above. However, I think it is interesting to note that accessing through an index always gives the single value whereas accessing through a condition returns a series. This is, b/c accessing with index clearly returns only one value whereas accessing through a condition can return several values.

Answer (score 0):

If one of the columns of your dataframe is the natural primary index for those data, then it's usually a good idea to make pandas aware of it by setting the `index` accordingly:

```py
df_my.set_index('id', inplace=True)
```

Now you can easily get just the `major` value for any `id` value `i`:

```py
df_my.loc[i, 'major']
```

Note that for `i = 3`, the output is `'Science'`, which is expected, as noted in the comments to your question above.